# .addClass() where data-id equals data-category?

Tags: jquery

Here I have constructed a fiddle, I cant think of how to `.addClass` where the clicked data-id equals the data-category. Take a look at the fiddle, you will understand much better.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQabJ/5/)**

Here I just `.addClass` to all the `.item` classes, Im not sure how to write it so that it adds class to the data-category that matches the data-id.

**Uncompleted jQuery Snippet:**

```
  $(".breadcrumb-cell .breadcrumb").click(function () {
      var theID  = $(this).data("id"),
          theCAT = $('.item').attr("data-category"),
          item   = $('.item')

      //This just shows you that when you click the element it returns the data-id each click
      alert(theID);

      // Here I gave it a few shots but no success, so I just add .active to all
      item.addClass('active');

  });
```

This feels kinda noobish but I havent messed with this kind of write up (matching data attributes) so a little bump of knowledge would be stupendous.

**Answer:** *by: Sushanth --*

```
$(".breadcrumb-cell .breadcrumb").click(function () {
var theID = $(this).data("id"),
    $allItem = $('.item'),
    $currItem = $('.item[data-category=' + theID + ']')

$currItem.addClass('active');
$allItem.not($currItem).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQabJ/7/)

```
var items = $('.item');
$(".breadcrumb-cell .breadcrumb").click(function () {
    var theID  = $(this).data("id");

    items.filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('category') === theID;
    }).addClass('active');

});
```

You can use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method. This is useful if you're going to be using `items` elsewhere as well as for this.

Comment: Actually, going through the code and implementing it on the live site, this method works better for me.. This is hard because both these answers are amazing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this selector

```
  $('.item[data-category=' + theID + ']').addClass('active');
```

This selector matches all the items that has a specific `data-category`

**Code**

```
$(".breadcrumb-cell .breadcrumb").click(function () {
    // This will have the category
    var theID = $(this).data("id"),
    //  All items
        $allItem = $('.item');

    // Current item is should be active
    var $currItem = $('.item[data-category=' + theID + ']');
    $('.item[data-category=' + theID + ']').addClass('active');
    // Remove the active class for other items
    $allItem.not($currItem).removeClass('active');
});
```

**[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/kQabJ/8/)**

Comment: I like this answer.. but why didnt you use the var `$currItem` under where you made the var? check the OP I did a little adjustment, could you tell me if it's wrong? It works fine in the fiddle

Comment: Not a problem at all. That can surely be done. Just wrote it this way so that it is clear as that is the main selector for this question

Comment: Oh ok I had a feeling you might have done that for clarification, I just wanted to make sure... thanks! I can now refer to this if this ever comes up again.

Comment: I have a tendency to prefix jquery objects with `$`, so that they won't get mixed up with normal variables.  Glad to have helped :)

Comment: This was the easiest solution in my situation. Thanks, @Sushanth--